# RegExp search and replace path to image in css

Tags: css, regex

It is necessary to perform a search and replace strings in css file. And found only the title picture with.

While the search is done so with the exception of

```
/:(\s*)url\(((.(?!.*https:|.*http:|.*base64|.*data:image))*)\)/ig
```

and replace

```
:$1url(\'../dist/img/vendor/$2\')
```

In this case, I replace the path in a similar way. And I get this result

```
background-image: url('../dist/img/vendor/"../images/preloader.gif"');
```

A need of a string

```
background-image: url("../images/preloader.gif");
```

get

```
background-image: url('../dist/img/vendor/preloader.gif');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
/(url\(\s*[\"\'])(?:[^\"\']+\/)?([^\/\"\']+[\"\']\s*\))/ig
```

Replace

```
$1../dist/img/vendor/$2
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/kU7cC9/3

Answer (score 0):

Using a css parser is a better way if you want among other things to avoid quotes problems (single quotes, double quotes, no quotes).

As an aside, the `background-image` CSS property isn't the only one that can contain a path to an image file, since the `background` property can compile all the data from other `background-` properties.

An example with [sabberworm PHP CSS Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) that automatically encloses paths between double quotes:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('NEW_PATH', '../dist/img/vendor/');

$oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($css);
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();

$properties = ['background-image', 'background'];

foreach($oCssDocument->getAllRuleSets() as $oRuleSet) {
    foreach($properties as $property) {
        $oCssRules = $oRuleSet->getRules($property);

        foreach ($oCssRules as $oCssRule) {
            $value = $oCssRule->getValue()->__toString();

            if (!preg_match('~https?:|base64|data:image~S', $value)) {
                $value = preg_replace('~url\("\K(?:[^"/]*/)*~', NEW_PATH, $value);
                $oCssRule->setValue($value);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $oCssDocument->render(Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::createPretty());
```

Comment: Thanks, but replacement was needed by the Grunt.js